# Sort array list based on most recent date in mm/dd/yy format in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an array based on sold date which in the format of MM/dd/yy. Currently, I'm getting wrong date in the first object of the array after sorting. The expected date in the first object in the sorted array is `01/12/24`.

**Code**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Car{
    String name;
    String sold;
    public Car(String name, String sold){
        this.name = name;
        this.sold = sold;
    }
    public String getSold(){
        return this.sold;
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    
      List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
      list.add(new Car("bmw", "01/12/24"));
      list.add(new Car("jeep", "02/12/23"));
      list.add(new Car("audi", "12/12/23"));
      
      List<Car> sortedList = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getSold).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
      
      System.out.println("sorted "+ sortedList.get(0).sold);
    }
}
```

I created a working example using [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/PFV). Could anyone please help?

Comment: You should probably use a real date object, like [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). These implement the Comparable interface and therefore should work fine with streams and their methods.

Comment: `MM/dd/yy` is not suitable for lexicographic comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse sold date as a date and compare by it:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");
    List<Car> sortedList = list.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.<Car, LocalDate>comparing(car -> LocalDate.parse(car.getSold(), dayFormatter)).reversed())
            .toList();
```

Comment: The `<Car, LocalDate>` part should not be needed.

Answer (score 2):

The sorting problem is because the date you are trying to sort by is a string. You need to convert it to LocalDate.
I added the soldDate variable of type LocalDate which will contain the value of the string date transformed to LocalDate. You will use this for sorting.
Updated code to catch the error and eliminate the string from the class as suggested.

```java
    import java.util.*;
    import java.time.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.stream.*;
    
    class Car{
        String name;
        LocalDate soldDate;
        public Car(String name, String sold){
            this.name = name;
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy");
            try {
                this.soldDate = LocalDate.parse(sold, formatter);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid date format: " + sold);
            }
        }
    
        public LocalDate getSold(){
            return this.soldDate;
        }
    }
    
    public class MyClass {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
        
          List<Car> list = new ArrayList<Car>();
          list.add(new Car("bmw", "01/12/24"));
          list.add(new Car("jeep", "02/12/23"));
          list.add(new Car("audi", "12/12/23"));
          
          List<Car> sortedList = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Car::getSoldDate).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
          
          if(!sortedList.isEmpty()) {
              System.out.println("sorted " + sortedList.get(0).sold);
          } else {
              System.out.println("No cars with valid date format found");
          }
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI: `LocalDate.parse` will throw a `DateTimeParseException` which you're currently no handling

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Define a class with appropriate data types.

```
record CarSale ( String name , LocalDate whenSold ) {}
```

Then build a `List`, and call `List#sort`.

```
new ArrayList<>(
    List.of(
        new Car( "bmw", LocalDate.parse( "2024-01-12" ) ) ,
        new Car( "jeep", LocalDate.parse( "2023-02-12" ) ) ,
        new Car( "audi", LocalDate.parse( "2023-12-12" ) )
    )
)
.sort( CarSales :: whenSold )
```

## Details

If the main purpose of your class is to transparently communicate immutable data, define as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

Represent date-time values using date-time classes. For a date-only value, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
record CarSale ( String name , LocalDate whenSold ) {}
```

The code calling upon this `CarSale` class should be parsing textual inputs as needed. (It is *not* the job of `CarSale` to clean up poorly formatted input text. See [*Separation of concerns*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).)

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uu" ) ;

String input = "01/12/24" ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Pass to the implicit constructor of our `CarSale` class.

```
CarSale cs = new CarSale( nameInput , ld ) ;
```

Collect those `CarSale` objects in a modifiable `List` such as a `ArrayList`.

```
List< CarSale > carSales = new ArrayList <>() ;
carSales.add( cs ) ;
```

Lastly, sort your list.  Pass a method reference to the getter method for the `LocalDate` object we populated. Objects of that class `LocalDate` know how to sort themselves.

```
carSales.sort( CarSales :: whenSold ) ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data exchange of date-time values.